# How do I get the covariance matrix if I only have one sensor - Kalmanfilter

Tags: matlab, control-theory, covariance, optimal-control, kalman-filter

How do I get the covariance matrix if I only got one sensor at measureing? Ḯ'm going to develope a LQG regulator.

[image]

If you look at this picture. The C-matris is like [1 0 0 0 0 0], then the I-matrix must be just a one dimension vector $n(t)$ ?

The same as the J-matrix. If B-matris is [0; 30; 0; 0; 0; 0], then the J-matrix must be like [0; 1 ;0 ;0 ;0 ;0]

**Question:** $$ $$ 
How do I compute the covariance matrix for noise and disturbance? How should a noise and disturbance vector look like? Can they be one dimension? Or do they need to be the same dimension as the A-matrix?

Comment: You're introducing noise to $y(t)$ so it should have the same dimension as $y(t)$. Your disturbance on the other hand gets added to your state dynamics and should therefore have the same dimension as $x(t)$. It's not quite clear what dimensions you have, please state that (for $x$, $u$, $y$, $\hat{x} etc.)

Also, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), co-variance on a scalar is its variance.

Comment: Okej! Let say that $x(t)$ has dimension 6 and then the $d(t)$ should have the dimension 6, even that J is just the same as B e.g [0;40; 0  ;0 ;0 ;0] and $y(t)$ is dimension 1 then covariance matrix for the noise should just be a constant, but covariance matrix for disturbance should be a matrix, due to the $x(t)$ dimension?

Comment: Just for precision, I think $d(t)$ should either be added to $u(t)$ before $B$ (in the case that it's noise to the control input) or $J$ should not be assumed to be the same as $B$ (if it's noise added to the dynamics).

Comment: In real life $d(t)$ is added to $u(t)$. But still...I know the disturbance vector $d$ and it need to have the same dimension as $x(t)$. But the problem is matrix $B$. The dimension of $B$ is the same dimension of $x(t)$, but B is example [0; 3.3; 0; 0; 0; 0]. And if the disturbance vector is $[d_1; d_2; d_3; d_4; d_5; d_6]$, then it make no sense beacuse B = [0; 3.3; 0; 0; 0; 0]. How can I even measure $d(t)$ ? Isin't it better to assume $d(t)$ has the same dimension as $u(t)$ insted?

Comment: So I guess it depends what you wnat $d(t)$ to be. If it is noise on your control input it should be added to $u(t)$ before $B$, and the effect of the $0$s in $B$ is a result of the mapping between control input and state, and not a problem. Otherwise, it is noise on your dynamics, and should be the same size as $x(t)$. In this second case, $J$ determines the nature of your noise: the standard is to have $J=I$, the identity matrix, which implies equal noise on all states. You may have something else for reasons of scaling, or if you expect some states to be noisier, etc.

Comment: Yes!. I want to add $d (t) $ to $u (t) $ but $d (t) $ need to have the same dimension as $x (t) $, or else, I cannot compute the covarianse matrix for disturbance. What do I need to do?

Comment: Well I don't quite agree... either $d(t)$ is noise of the control input, and has the dimension of $u(t)$, or it is noise of the dynamics, has the dimension of $x(t)$ and is added to the dynamics, where you've shown in your figure.

Comment: But how do I compute the kalman gain matrix K if $d (t) $ is one dimension? Look at the matlab lqe () command.